# RAID 1 on internal hdd + usb external hdd?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, raid

Unfortunately my internal HDD is probably going to die soon and I do not have money for a new one. But I have an external HDD which I was using as a backup, so I thought of a solution: RAID

But I have some questions, because I would like to get it right the first time.

```
my internal Hdd      External Hdd (USB 2.0)                   
Seagate              Seagate
500 GB               1 TB       
5200 rpm             7200 rpm
```

I want to mirror internal hdd on extrenal hdd and use the remaining 500 GB on external for backup (software raid 1) so that when my disc finally dies I will have another up to date disc ready.

first of all:

1) is it even possible? I have been studying about raids for some time and didnt found why this shouldnt work (just that the slower hdd will be bottleneck, but I dont care about that) But than I read somewhere that internal hdd is "dynamic" and external not, so it cant be used for booting up system (I dont really what is this about)

If yes than

2) Do the partitions in the raid need to be at the exactly the same place? I know they have to be the same size, but will it matter if I will make RAID from e.g. /dev/sda1 primary part. at the begining of disc and /dev/sdb5 logical part. at the end of disc (e.g. I would not do that, just because I also want to have my win partition on internal HDD, but I don't want to raid it too. It has about 20 GB just for games and I don't want to put it at the end of disc, because of disc head traveling, I will rather have static data (movies, music, images... ) at the end of disc (I tried it in VBox and it worked fine)

3) is there any difference between having one big raid partition with lvm on top of it vs having separated raid 1 for every partition? (will lvm adds to CPU usage? latency? will be many raid partitions a little safer than having one partition?)

EDIT: I found out that I can do cfdisk /dev/mdX and create another partitions, so that would probably be the best solution, right?
(also I am running gentoo linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think it could theoretically be possible, but it's going to be horribly slow. If your machine can boot from USB, you should be able to boot from an external disk, but that can be thrown off by additional usb disks (that steal the disk label before it gets it).
2. Not in linux software raid. It can affect performance, but there is no need for it to be on the same place on the disk.
3. It might be an issue if you have one single RAID partition and have bad sectors, but this is just a theory on my part.. I tend to make multiple smaller RAID partitions, as errors on that partition won't take out one half of your raid partition, just the part with errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 2GiB or more RAM? If so, investigate on using ZFS as filesystem.

And use more than two disks.

For what i have read about ZFS (it allows compression on the fly, also encryption) it has also something really good that no RAID can do: Integrity check on the fly.

RAID must not be used, no matter how say another thing, if your data is really important, RAID does not warranty data is correctly written to disks (it can not know if data on a sector is correct or has been altered, no checksum is calculated, no hash, etc).

Personally i am using RAID-0 with three disks (PATA about 28MiB/s and each SATA about 45MiB/s), so i get arround 105MiB/s (adding the PATA reaches the bottleneck since PCI-32 33MHz can not sustain the three HDDs bandwith 2xSATA+1xPATA plus all cards, and gain by adding PATA is only 15MiB/s, but all counts), also more, adding the PATA causes the SATAs to not be used at max bandwidth, so they work on relax, also the PATA works on relax way since bottleneck is at PCI bus, so the HDDs have some time to cold them selfes (something most people do not care about)... why i use so fast HDDs that they are doing nothing half of the time? just to not over heat them and no need to have them on refrigerated room! Also to enlarge their live really a lot!

The there diks i test:

- Internal PATA HDD
- Internal SATA HDD
- Internal SATA HDD

Migrating to ZFS do not get things better? Oh, yes and no; since compresion is ON it gains a lot, now (with compressible data) i can sustain a near 105MiB/s (compressed data) and since compression is near 2.5:1 i can read/write real uncompressed data at more than 261MiB/s on best cases.

The bad side, ZFS is eating 1.3GiB of my RAM (i only have 2GiB, motherboard maximum possible).

After thinking a little and trying a lot of tweaking a lot i could add an USB 2.0 HDD to the zfs pool (i wanted in a way i can remove it after the tests, that is a lot hard)... basically i solved it by takeing apart all HDDs and put other ones i have on a desk without use, then do the test with ZFS on (all acting as dynamic stripping, zfs stripe size is dynamic):

- Internal PATA HDD
- Internal SATA HDD
- Internal SATA HDD
- External USB 2.0 to Sata HDD (only one HDD, since USB 2.0 is bottleneck for that disk)

If i do that configuration on Raid0, i would get 25MiB/s*4=100MiB/s, so now the limit is not by PCI at 105MiB/s (video, audio, etc., cards use part of the bandwidth), it is by adding the really slow 2.0 USB max speed, it lowers (on Raid0) the speed of all (Raid0 needs all stripes of same size, so bandwith to all HDDs is the same, as high as the lowest one).

If done on ZFS, since stripes size is dynamic, if no compression at all, i can get the sum of bandwidth (28 PATA + 2*45 SATA + 25 USB = 142MiB/s)? No and no, again the limit is PCI BUS (105MiB/s because all other cards), so i get only 105MiB/s uncompressed data transfer... so no gain (on speed) by adding the USB one, something i knew before starting, PCI bus is the botleneck.

I know you are talking about RAID 1 (mirror), for writes Raid 1 needs to write to all the disks the same amount of info on each one, so speed is the slowest one, but on reads it can read different things form each disk (if configured for so) so it can go up to as much as Raid 0, so my tests on Raid 0 can make some light, and since i tested Raid 0 agaist ZFS, ... all is said.

The good part of ZFS is the native compression (no matter if you put files or put partitions, it compress the blocks) and the validation on data.

So having ZFS with some level of RAID is much better than mdadm, etc., but at a high cost on RAM used.

I recomend not to use DeDup on ZFS... it can requiere huge amount of RAM, more than 32GiB of ram on 1TiB disks.

Also i recomend using small HDDs fast enough and not to tend to use huge HDDs. It is much better to have 8 HDD of 120GiB, than 2 of 500GiB; but put a warning on having enough ports and enough power drain.

Answer (score 0):

1) Is it even possible?

Yes, it is possible, but not trivial.

> I have been studying about RAID for some time and did not found why this
>   should not work (just that the slower HDD will be bottleneck, but I do not
>   care about that)

The USB bus will be the bottleneck. An average speed for USB2 is about 30 MB/second. Both disks are likely to be much faster than that.

> But than I read somewhere that internal HDD is "dynamic" and external not,
>   so it cant be used for booting up system (I do not really what is this about)

A dynamic disk as in [this ms way](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/what-are-basic-and-dynamic-disks)? On Gentoo?

> If yes then
>
> 2) do the partitions in the RAID need to be at the exactly the same place?

No. Mdadm will happily create a mirror with two volumes as long as both are the same size.

> 3) is there any difference between having one big RAID partition with lvm on top
>   of it vs having separated RAID 1 for every partition?

Both methods will work.

Creating a mirror spanning the whole disk is the simplest solution. Creating several smaller mdX devices is more work, but can be more flexible.

> (will lvm add to CPU usage? Latency?

Any extra layer will add to latency.

I am not sure if that is significant or not when you also use a USB drive.

> will be many raid partitions a little safer than having one partition?)

No. If the disk fails it fails. It does not care what is written on it, or how you see that data on it.

---

You did not ask how to do it, but it is probably best to:

1. Get a backup all all your data on a disk you are not adding the the RAID. This will might require a third disk.
2. Create the mirror on the external drive. Use the `missing` option to skip the internal drive.
3. Format your volume(s) on the new volume on your '1 disk / mirror / degraded`
4. Copy all the data to it.
5. Test if it works. (Possibly discover that the bootloader needs tweaking)
6. Add the internal HDD to the mirror.

If you are unsure about any step, first make a full disk backup. [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is a free tool which can do this.

---

Lastly, before you do all this:

- Are you sure the disk is dying?  Did you check the SMART values? Does the number of reallocated sectors increase?
- If it is failing, would it be easier to just replace the HDD rather than using a second drive?
- If you can not afford a second drive, consider swapping the drives (e.g. use the faster external drive in the computer and move the possible failing slow drive to the USB2 case.

Comment: A dynamic disk as in this ms way? On Gentoo? - yes I was confused what were they talking about. Yeah thanks for the advices, I already planned how to do it, but I didnt thought about replacing the harddrivers, that would be a great idea, but I am afraid it wouldnt be possible (I have laptop (which I am practically using as desktop) and the external hdd is pretty big, and I am big noob in anything hardware-like) so I thought about a) using only external hdd over usb b) use them both in raid

Comment: and yes, SMART said it is time to replace the hdd, and it sometimes does that click noice when it moves its head to the remapped spare sector, but despite that it is still working (for a few months now) I will try zero the whole disk, mayby it isnt really dying and I am just really sensitive about the disc sound in quiet room, and that would help)